# Initialization of a struct

Tags: c, struct, initialization

Is there possible to initialize a object-table of a struct in c before main? I've got this struct:

```
typedef struct customer{
    int x, y;// coordinates
    int quantity;

} customer; 

customer *table1;

int main(){

    table1 = (customer *)malloc(n * sizeof(customer));

    table1[0].quantity = 0;    table1[0].x = 0; table1[0].y = 0;  //afetiria
    table1[1].quantity = 1000; table1[1].x = 0; table1[1].y = 12; // 1st 
    table1[2].quantity = 1500; table1[2].x = 6; table1[2].y = 5;  // 2nd
    table1[3].quantity = 800;  table1[3].x = 7; table1[3].y = 15; // 3rd

    distance(1,2) //calculate the distance bet 1st and 2d object 

}
```

As I wanna make a distance function I noticed that it doesn't work ifI initialize struct inside `main`. Any idea about how can I initialize globally `table1`?

Comment: Don't cast the return value of `malloc()` in a C program.

Comment: What does exactly mean? I mean how can i use malloc without cast the type that i use?

Comment: The return type of malloc is void * -- you do not need to cast it. Just remove the cast, it will work fine.

Comment: You do not show "n" being declared or initialized. This is clearly not your actual code -- it would not compile. We therefore cannot give you a real answer to why your initialization is failing.

Comment: Show us the code for your `distance()` function; the problem is likely there.

Comment: OK it works!! But what about the case you have an array of integers and you cast malloc (int*) its the same mistake?

Comment: Yes, it's exactly the same.  Don't do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example of a global initialization for your array:

```
customer table1[] = { { 0, 0, 0 }, 
                      { 0, 12, 1000 },
                      { 6, 5, 1500 },
                      { 7, 15, 800 } };
```

However, what you have shown of your code should be pretty much equivalent.

Comment: Yea i want to create a table of objects not just a 2d table.

Comment: The example I gave is exactly that, an array of structures.

Answer (score 0):

You can move the `malloc` call outside main, but that should make no difference. As long as `table1` is declared outside of main, which it is in your example, it should be visible to the entire translation unit.

Comment: The problem is the initialization, not the size of the table. When i use distance it returns 0 instead of the actually value.

Comment: @FereRes - have you gone through with a debugger? Those assignment statements clearly happen before the call to distance, so table1 should be set during the execution of the distance function.